# How to subclass int and use isinstance to identify instances of it?

Tags: python, subclass, python-2.x, isinstance

I want to subclass `int` (or some other analogous builtin numerical type), that I can explicitly type check.

This q&a is similar, but didn't answer what I'm seeing exactly:
[Sub-classing a built-in Python type such as int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032765/sub-classing-a-built-in-python-type-such-as-int)

Here's a rough example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class MyId( int ) : pass 

class MyCollection() :

    def __init__( self ):
        self.__id = MyId( 0 )

    def nextId( self ) :        
        self.__id+=1
        print "isinstance",  isinstance(self.__id, MyId)
        return self.__id
```

Unfortunately, my invocation of `isinstance` returns `False`. How do I make it succeed (ideally with this same basic concept)? It's obvious how to achieve is this by giving MyId class a "has a" rather than "is a" relationship with `int`... but I thought it be nicer to just make it an `int` with a specific "name".

Currently, I'm writing this in Py2, but any cross version answers are appreciated if applicable.

Comment: If you don't want to implement all the relevant magic methods (`__add__, __radd__, etc.`) in `MyId`, you could just go with `self.__id = MyId(self.__id + 1)`.

Comment: If your goal is to type check, why not just just check that `__id` is an `int`? `isinstance(self.__id, int)`

Comment: I agree with @axblount as I don't really understand here the need of overriding the builtin int.

Comment: Thanks, @schwobaseggl . That's definitely in the running for the "best" solution.  It's shorter, but I hate that it requires a client class having to understand what equates to a private implementation detail.  I also don't care for destroying an object and creating a new one, just to change a value.  Essentially, we have an immutable int in that case.

Comment: As I wrote in another comment here, btw: The point is to determine whether some polymorphic functions are returning and/or dealing with a specific kind of object, because the context of what to do with such will hinge on that. I need to differentiate between an int and this "id type".

Comment: @BuvinJ for this case I would use composition instead of inheritance. An id is not a special integer. Dividing an id makes no sense for example.

Comment: Yeah.  I ended up doing that.  I just thought I could take a really short and sweet approach.  Rather than wrapping an `int`, I figured I could just a derived class.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you need to override the `__add__` method.

If you don't override this method, it will use the builtin int `__add__` method which returns a new integer object.

See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836570/how-to-implement-iadd-for-an-immutable-type) which explains this behavior as mentioned by @martineau in comments.

```
class MyId( int ):
    def __add__(self, i):
        return MyId(super(MyId, self).__add__(i))

class MyCollection() :

    def __init__( self ):
        self.__id = MyId( 0 )

    def nextId( self ) :        
        self.__id += 1
        print "isinstance",  isinstance(self.__id, MyId)
        return self.__id

a = MyCollection()
a.nextId()
```

Prints: `isinstance True`

Comment: Would be a better answer if you explained _why_ `__add__()` needs to be implemented.

Comment: Hmm.  This is definitely a valid answer,  I upvoted it.  But, I'm not in love with it.  I hate the idea that I have to redefine add the functions that I'm trying to get for free.  That's the point of the sub classing.  @schwobaseggl answer (posted as a comment) might be better... But it's less than perfect too I think...

Comment: Am I going to have to override equality operators too? ... If so I'm not sure that I'm gaining anything by using int as a base...  I already saw couldn't print one of these objects implicitly...

Comment: @martineau that's because it is not totally clear in my head. Is that because int is immutable, so `__add__` needs to build a new (int) object ?

Comment: @BuvinJ you don't have to override equality operators, just operations that returns an "updated" integer.

Comment: Thanks @CorentinLimier.  Note that I could not print the object, nor format it with %d... There were a series of built-in `int` features that just wouldn't work.  I find that terribly strange.  See my "answer" for a somewhat more comprehensive definition of the sort of needs I have for the object.

Comment: In the real use case, I have functions which can return multiple types.  One of them, is this id, which indicates that the real answer will be provided asynchronously.  There is a whole other set of mechanisms involving in multiple producers and consumers using this "collection" and "id"...

Comment: I second the question on immutability.  Is an `int` immutable?  It makes since that a string is, since that involves reallocating more memory, etc. potentially, but can't an int just be overwritten in the same memory location?

Comment: @CorentinLimier.  So, it turns out ints are immutable in Python.  I didn't realize that.  Here an SO post explaining why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431314/why-python-data-types-are-immutable

Comment: Corentin: No, it's because without defining the method for the `MyId` class the one inherited from the built-in `int` class gets used—so the `self.__id += 1` statement effectively turns `self.__id` into an `int`. You can verify this puttng a `print "isinstance",  isinstance(self.__id, MyId)` _before_ and after it.

Comment: @martineau yeah I knew that but I was wondering why the builtin `__add__`was returning a new int object but I realize now it has nothing to do with immutability : I don't have an example of `__add__` function that does not return a new object.

Comment: Corentin: It's complicated. See the answers (and the many excellent comments) to a question I asked [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836570/how-to-implement-iadd-for-an-immutable-type), that **almost** makes this question a duplicate of it (once you realize that it's the `+=` messing things up, that is).

Comment: Corentin: I now think your answer would be more correct if it implemented `__iadd__()` — but I upvoted it anyway because it's on the right track.

Comment: @martineau thanks for the link I added it to the answer. Will help OP and others to dig into the subject.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're after is being able to check that values being passed around have been created in a specific way. In *Python 3.5.2+* there is the `typing` module that provides [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype). This allows you to do static analysis of your code to make sure it's doing the things you expect it to do. The example given in the documentation is:

> ```
> from typing import NewType
>
> UserId = NewType('UserId', int)
> some_id = UserId(524313)
> ```
>
> The static type checker will treat the new type as if it were a subclass of the original type. This is useful in helping catch logical errors:
>
> ```
> def get_user_name(user_id: UserId) -> str:
>     ...
>
> # typechecks
> user_a = get_user_name(UserId(42351))
>
> # does not typecheck; an int is not a UserId
> user_b = get_user_name(-1)
> ```

No actual type checking is performed at runtime, and the value returned by `NewType` is just a pass-through function that returns its argument unchanged. This also means you cannot do things like `isinstance(obj, UserId)`, since `UserId` is not an actual class. What is does mean is, as mentioned by the documentation, static type checkers will help uncover logical errors -- which seems like what you're after.

Comment: I like this idea, but it doesn't create a separate type. `type(UserId(1)) == int` is true. `UserId` itself is a function not a type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subclassing `int` just check that your instance variable is an `int`.

```
class MyCollection():

    def __init__( self ):
        self.__id = 0

    def nextId( self ) :        
        self.__id += 1
        print "isinstance",  isinstance(self.__id, int)
        return self.__id
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't serve my needs.  The point is to determine whether some polymorphic functions are returning and/or dealing with a specific kind of object, because the context of what to do with such will hinge on that.  I need to differentiate between an int and this "id type"

Comment: Then I think a 'has a' relationship is your best. It sounds like you don't want `__id` to be treated like an int. The best way to prevent that is by creating a new class.

Comment: I guess I need to go with a damn "has a" after all.  See my (displeasing...) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per Dunes' suggestion, I simply dropped the entire `int` concept entirely. As he pointed out, any vanilla object can implicitly be used as a unique key!

In fact `MyId` could be defined as simply: `class MyId: pass`. Often, that would be it - a perfectly usable, implicitly unique key!

For my use case, however, I need to pass these keys back and forth across sub processes (via `multiprocessing` queues).  I ran into trouble with that ultra light weight approach, as the hash value would change when the objects where pickled and pushed across processes.  A minor secondary concern was that I wanted to make these objects easy to log and manually read / match up through logs.  As such, I went with this:

```
class _MyIdPrivate: pass
class MyId :
    def __init__( self ):
        self.__priv = _MyIdPrivate() 
        self.__i = hash( self.__priv )            
    def __str__( self ): return str( self.__i )
    def __hash__( self ): return self.__i
    def __eq__( self, other ): 
        try: return self.__i == other.__i
        except: return False     

class MyCollection :

    def __init__( self ):
        self.__objs={}

    def uniqueId( self ): return MyId()

    def push( self, i, obj ):
        self.__objs[ i ] = obj     

    def pop( self, i ):
        return self.__objs.pop( i, None )     

c = MyCollection()
uId = c.uniqueId()
print "uId", uId
print "isinstance", isinstance(uId, MyId)
c.push( uId, "A" )
print c.pop( MyId() )
print c.pop( uId )
```

As you can see, I wrapped the short and sweet approach into a more comprehensive/verbose one. When I create the MyId object, I create a _MyIdPrivate member, and take the hash of that at that moment of creation.  When pickling, and pushing across sub projects, that _MyIdPrivate hash will change - but it doesn't matter because I captured the initial value, and everything ends up pivoting off of that.

The main benefit of this approach over the original `int` plan is that I get a unique key without "calculating" or assigning it directly.

As Dunes' suggested I could have also used a uuid. I can see pros and cons to that vs this...

Comment: Combining `__hash__` and your `increment` method is a very bad idea. Objects should not have mutable hash values, or at the very least should not be mutated whilst they are keys in a mapping. If do you need mutate the hash value of a key then you will not be able to reference it any more. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__ for more details.

Comment: Good point, @Dunes!  I can see the logical flaw in what I have here.  Can you suggest a specific rewrite for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: I revised and re-posted.  Better?

Comment: I don't quite get why you want what you want. It's a bit of an anti-pattern for python -- the "if it acts/quacks like a duck" thing. I get the impression you're not overly familiar with Python and are trying to force it to behave more like a statically typed language. Your new implementation looks like it will work and is along the lines of what I would have suggested to make this work.

Comment: I am quite familiar with Python.  The entire point to all this is the fact that it is a weakly typed language.  I have a situation where it makes perfect sense for some functions to return and or handle multiple types, one of which is a key to collection.

Comment: I need to differentiate between an `int` and key (which is an `int` essentially).  This is why, all I wanted to do was sub class `int` in a single line.  Now, I'm forced into way more ugliness than I wanted, because that has proved to not work in several critical matters.

Comment: I can think of multiple alternate solutions to my use case potentially, but a quick type checking should be by far the easiest.

Comment: You still haven't said why your key needs to be an int. What functionality of an int does it need? If you just need a unique identifier with a distinct class that can be hashed, then `class MyId(object): pass` should suffice. And then `nextId` can just return `MyId()`. Your keys will be guaranteed unique whilst they are still reachable.

Comment: re: typing. Strong/Weak typing as terms aren't overly useful as most languages include aspects of both, including Python and C/C++. Python is a dynamically type checked, type safe and memory safe language. Whereas C/C++ are statically type checked, not type safe and not memory safe.

Comment: Brilliant!  You are totally right.  Thanks so much, @Dunes!  I've revised the answer.

Comment: @Dunes, so now I have problem, perhaps you can answer.  When I push this across processes using mutliprocessing, it seems that I lose the hash!  I need these keys to cross back forth across such.  I did have that with `int` approach.  Is there a serialize/deserialize way to handle this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184557/discussion-between-dunes-and-buvinj).